# doctor fees for lawyer services

Tags: us-constitution

I am a physician and almost routinely am inundated with forms from lawyers to fill for my patients so they can get disability. They get paid for these cases but expect me to fill these forms at no cost.

Am I legally bound to fill these at no cost to my patients or their lawyers?

Comment: Are these residual functional capacity (RFC) assessments? You may want to look at: http://www.disabilitysecrets.com/page11-38.html

Comment: Are you being asked to provide copies of records or an opinion?

Answer (score 2):

If you are an independent professional providing a professional service then, *prima facie*, you are entitled to negotiate a fee for that service, including choosing to provide it *pro bono*.

There may be limits to this due to the interaction of other contracts that you may have, for example, with insurance companies. It is also possible that there are statutory limits or restrictions. In both cases, I would ask the person who claimed that they existed to show them to you.